# Is the HTTP package server safe to use in production?

Tags: http, go

Go implements [FastCGI](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/net/http/fcgi/), as well as a native [HTTP server](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/net/http/) in its standard library.

Is it safe to use the server from the HTTP package in production (as an application server) or is it recommended to use the FastCGI interface to connect to a more robust solution like Apache in terms of security?

Comment: I don't know about Go and security, but keep in mind most webserves can reverse proxy http also. I have used nginx for this and it works nicely, simple to setup and lots of features like load balancing. The up side is you can still connect directly to your Go server internally for testing with HTTP.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go's http package is intended for production use, but it hasn't put in the time to prove itself like Apache or Nginx. There may still be issues lurking. One thing I can think of is the potential DoS attack path available right now: http://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=2630

We use Go's http package directly in production where I work. We haven't had any problems with it so far.